# Add video controls to CreateJS/EaselJS canvas

Tags: javascript, video, createjs

I'm displaying a video in a canvas using CreateJS/EaselJS, and it's working fine:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
background = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(background);

videoDOM = document.createElement('video');
videoDOM.src = 'videos/espace_clients.webm';

if($.browser.msie) videoDOM.src = 'videos/espace_clients.mp4';
if($.browser.opera) videoDOM.src = 'videos/espace_clients.ogv';
videoDOM.autoplay = true;

video = new createjs.Bitmap(videoDOM);

stage.addChild(video);
```

Now I'd like to add basic playback controls (pause, play, rewind). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this is easy to do! Just let the target video object handle it:

```
buttonPause.addEventListener("click", clickHandler); 

function clickHandler(pEvent)
{
    videoDOM.pause();
}
```